# Less css &:hover

Tags: less

How can I create this class with less?

```
.class {
    display: none;
}

a:hover .class {
    display: block; 
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Like this?

```
.class {
    display: none;

    a:hover & {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 15):

```
.class {
  display: none;

  &:hover {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming from your given CSS code that your HTML structure is like so:

```
<a>
    <div class="class">Content</div>
</a>
```

You'll be happy to know that what you want to achieve is fairly easy using Less; here's the code shown below:

```
a {
    &:hover {
        .class {
            //Apply styling here
        }
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.